# Discord.py Links in Embeds

Tags: discord.py

I am looking to put an invite link to my bot in the description of the embed as a hyperlink. I want it to display something similar to **click here** and then lead to the bot's invite link. If anybody knows how to do this, if you could please advise me that would be great! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like so: `[text to click](url)`

Note: This won't work in the **title**, **footer** or **field titles**, if you want a hyperlink in the title use the `url` kwarg

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
 async def invite(ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color= discord.Colour.dark_teal() # or any color you want
        )
        embed.add_field(name='If you wish to add me in your server,' ,value='[Click here to add]( bot link )', inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

You can put hyperlinks in this way just in field value.

Comment: You rejected my edit and edited it further. Was it intentional? Please click 'Improve' next time.